# creating a palindrome html page, function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. I'm creating a html page that takes an input and checks in that input is a palindrome. I created two functions, one to reverse the string and other to validate if its a palindrome. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my functions. I have tried debugging using the console but nothing so far.

Here is the code that I have

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Text Validation</title>
    <script>

      function reverseString(str) {
          return str.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
      }

      function Validation() {
          firstStr = document.getElementById('user')
          secondStr = reverseString(firstStr)
          if (firstStr == secondStr) {
              alert("passed palindrome");
          }
          else {
              alert("failed palindrome");

          }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b> Enter a random word </b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="textbox" id="user">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <td align = "right" colspan = "2">
        <input  type="button"  id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick =
                "Validation();">
      </td>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's close -- you need to get the value from the element: `firstStr = document.getElementById('user').value`

Comment: Hey there, algorithmically speaking, I believe you could make the thing faster using 2 pointers and moving them along the same String (one on each end). Your worst case (and even best case), using such a technique, would always be faster to calculate than your best case with your current approach. It'd also require less memory. (Sorry if it's irrelevant, just thought I'd let you know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to extract the value from the `user` element like so:

```
var firstStr = document.getElementById('user').value;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
}

function Validation() {
var firstStr = document.getElementById('user').value;
var secondStr = reverseString(firstStr)
if (firstStr == secondStr) {
    alert("passed palindrome");
}
else {
    alert("failed palindrome");

   }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Text Validation</title> 
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b> Enter a random word </b>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="textbox" id="user">
</td>
</tr>
<td align = "right" colspan = "2">
  <input  type="button"  id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick = 
   "Validation();">
</td>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you have to do .value to get the input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value, using `document.getElementById('user').value`

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
}

function Validation() {
firstStr = document.getElementById('user').value
secondStr = reverseString(firstStr)

if (firstStr == secondStr) {
    alert("passed palindrome");
}
else {
    alert("failed palindrome");

   }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <b> Enter a random word </b>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="textbox" id="user">
</td>
</tr>
<td align = "right" colspan = "2">
  <input  type="button"  id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onClick = 
   "Validation();">
</td>
</table>
```